# Can I move and shift as a single move action in D&D 4E?

Tags: dnd-4e, movement

Let's suppose my character is in the middle of combat, and that he can move right in front of an opponent without using all his movement points (let's say he has 5 speed and he moves 4 squares). Can he now shift to another square next to the enemy to get a better position, in the same move action, or would that count as a second move action?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**No.**

**Shifting counts as a second move action**. What you'd be doing is "walking" or "running," then Shifting. Each of those takes a move action. (Rules Compendium, p. 203)

Answer (score 9):

**No.**

It costs an entire move action to shift (generally 1 square). It costs an entire move action to move *up to* your normal speed (generally 5 or 6 squares). You cannot combine them in a move action.

**However:**

There are powers that let you **shift more than 1 square**. If your move is 6 squares and somehow you gain a power that lets you shift 6 squares, you can effectively do what you're describing.

Some characters can **teleport**. This lets you move to any square within range you can see.

Last, you could **spend an action point**, if you have one, to take an additional move action and then shift into place.

Answer (score 5):

**No**.

You are combining two entirely different move actions.  Each move action has it's own benefits and drawbacks.  To be pedantic you should declare which move action you are taking prior to doing the movement.  When that action is concluded you can convert your standard action into a move action if you wish (assuming you hadn't used it prior).

Here are the generic move actions that allow you to move (and their restrictions).

- **Walk** <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=339)</sup> (move up to your speed)

  - If you leave a square adjacent to an enemy you provoke an opportunity attack from that enemy.
- **Shift** <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=335)</sup> (move 1 square)

  - You do not provoke opportunity attacks
  - You cannot shift into squares requiring more than 1 movement point (difficult terrain)
  - You cannot shift into terrain requiring a skill check
- **Run** <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=333)</sup> (Move up to your speed +2)

  - You take -5 to all attacks until the start of your next turn
  - You grant combat advantage until the start of your next turn
  - If you leave a square adjacent to an enemy you provoke an opportunity attack from that
- **Crawl** <sup>[DDI](http://www.wizards.com/dndinsider/compendium/glossary.aspx?id=326)</sup> (Move up to half your speed)

  - You must be prone to crawl
  - If you leave a square adjacent to an enemy you provoke an opportunity attack from that